# vb.net unwanted richtextbox resizing

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i have two richtextboxes of the exact same size located on my form. However, when I run it, one's height reduces. There are other controls around it so it leaves a weird space. What causes that?

[Form in the Design tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URCyw.png)

[Form once I run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3T85R.png)

I've tried constraining the control with the "same height" button, I've created a new richtextbox, but it keeps on happening.

It also depends on computers, on screens with unusual resolutions the box is the correct size.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Its because scroll bar coming in picture. In order to uniformly set the positions and sizes of RichtextBoxes use DOCKING or Anchoring properly
[image]

Comment: Oh the width is fine, it's the height that varies and bothers me. Everything is anchored top left.

Comment: And the scroll bar is just from the visual studio gui opened behind my form, it doesnt take any space on the form itself

Comment: This No of EEProm gus is also coming down . So might be this group need to be fixed.

Comment: WHat do you mean by fix the group?